# Boost jam, using absolute paths for dependencies

Tags: boost, build, bjam, boost-build

I have a jam file hierarchy as follows:

Jamroot:

```
lib foo : <file>/SOME/RANDOM/FILE ;

build-project p1 ;
build-project p2 ;
```

Jamfile in p1:

```
lib bar : bar.cpp
```

Jamfile in p2:

```
lib bar2 : bar2.cpp ../p1//bar ..//foo ;
```

So bar2 depends on bar and foo using relative paths.

Is it possible to write a single command in Jamroot so that I can write the following in Jamfile in p2 instead?

```
lib bar2 : bar2.cpp /p1//bar //foo ;
```

That would be more convenient as you don't need to think of the relative path anymore.
I know there is the `use-project` command, but 1) I would need to write a use-project for each of the subdirectories, 2) I don't know how to declare the root folder using use-project...

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can automate `use-project` declarations with `glob` and looping:

```
for p in [ glob */[jJ]amfile ]
{
    use-project /$(p:P) : ./$(p:P) ;
}
```

`:P` is for getting the parent directory. More on variable expansion [here](http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/jam/language.html#jam.language.variables.expansion)

2) Assigning a project-id to the current project isn't done with `use-project`, it's done with `project`:

`project /root ; # common requirements and other useful things can go here if needed` ([link](http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/overview/projects.html))

I don't think `//foo` is a valid syntax for a target reference. Also I don't think you can denote a target in a parent project with some target reference that doesn't contain a non-empty project-id (or path).

Finally you can write this in p2's Jamfile:

```
lib bar2 : bar2.cpp /p1//bar /root//foo ;
```